# How can I correctly create a new Spring MVC project with Maven structure using STS\Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I am using STS (the Elipse version for Spring framework) and I am finding some difficulties to create a new Spring MVC project that use Maven structure.

So I am trying to do something as shown in this tutorial: http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/creating-a-spring-mvc-project-using-maven-and-eclipse-in-one-minute

So I do: **File ---> New ---> Maven Project**

and when I come to the **Select an Archetype** wizard I select **All Categories** into the **Catalog** dropdown and it show this list of archetype:

[image]

As you can see there is no reference to any kind of Spring project and if I write "Spring" into the **Filter** I obtain no result.

Why? What am I missing?

Comment: Check https://ghariaonline.wordpress.com/2015/11/19/spring-mvc-and-spring-data-jpa-with-eclipselink-sitemesh-restful-web-service-annotation-based-configuration/ which has pre-configured Spring MVC project with spring data, sitemesh, RST etc.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the archetypes, use [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io) and import the Maven project it creates. If you have a recent version of STS, you can go to File->New->Spring Starter Project and fill out the form from the Eclipse wizard.

Comment: ok but what exactly is the difference of use the second way related to the classsic maven project?

Comment: @AndreaNobili Maven archetypes are basically template projects that you can clone, and they're artifacts just like dependencies or plugins. The Spring archetypes don't show up in Eclipse because you've never used them, and so they're not in your local repository; you could still use one by looking it up (perhaps on Central) and specifying its GAV coordinates.